# Onebox Twitch.tv links (both streams and archives) in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I'd love to see links to Twitch TV oneboxed in chat for both streams and archives.

So for the following link (Daigo vs. Xian at PAX):

http://www.twitch.tv/madcatz/b/453563519?t=2h32m20s

In chat, we would see:

[image: Mad Catz Unveiled at PAX Prime image placard]

This image is returned from the API call to [`GET /videos/:id`](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/videos.md#get-videosid) through the [Twitch API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/) in the `preview` field:

```
{
    "preview": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv.thumbs/archive-453563519-320x240.jpg",
    "game": "Divekick",
    "length": 18599,
    "views": 4249,
    "_id": "a453563519",
    "channel": {
        "display_name": "MadCatz",
        "name": "madcatz"
    },
    "title": "Mad Catz Unveiled at PAX Prime - TONIGHT at 8PM! - Giveaway details - Visit http://bit.ly/MCZFB",
    ....
}
```

Note that I'd like for it to be able to take me to the live channel (for live channel links) as well as take me to an archive (for archive links), as well as honoring the timestamps on the archive links (as in the example above).

Comment: Other useful things we could onebox while we're at it: Steam games, Kickstarter, Soundcloud.

Comment: Soundcloud isn't oneboxed yet?

Comment: This would be cool. I occasionally paste links to my stream or other's streams in chat